# Solving two coupled functional equations in the same time

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$ϕ(s)=f(s)\exp(ig(s))$, $s$ is a complex number.

The expressions of $f$ and $g$ are not known since they depend on the gamma function.

It is well known that we can solve a functional equation in different manners. However, I have two coupled functional equations of the form:

$g(1-s)+g(s)=0 \pmod{2\pi}$

and

$f(1-s)f(s)=1$

The objective is to determine $f$ and $g$ and their domain of definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition,
$$
\log(\phi(s))=\log(f(s))+ig(s)
$$
Assuming that $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are real-valued functions, we get that
$$
f(s) = |\phi(s)|
$$
and
$$
g(s) \equiv \arg(\phi(s))\pmod{2\pi}
$$
If we can't assume that $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are real-valued, then I don't believe there is a way to uniquely determine $f(s)$ and $g(s)$.

---

Since $\log(f(s))+\log(f(1-s))=0$, about the only thing we can say is that $\log\left(f\left(s+\frac12\right)\right)$ is an odd function of $s$. That is, $f(s)=e^{h\left(s-\frac12\right)}$, where $h(s)$ is any odd function.

A similar argument shows that $g(s)=k\left(s-\frac12\right)+\pi e\left(s-\frac12\right)$ where $k(s)$ is any odd function and $e(s)$ is any even, integer-valued function.

Comment: @RH1: there is not much that can be said about $f$ and $g$, but I think I have described them as much as possible from the relations given.

Comment: @ robjohn: Ok, this is a great answer. thank you very much.

Comment: @ robjohn: the function $g(s)=k\left(s-\frac12\right)+\pi e\left(s-\frac12\right)$ is modulo $2π$. So $πe(s-1/2)$ represent the corresponding addition modulo $2π$. I am right!

Comment: @RH1: yes. Being even, $\pi e\left(s-\frac12\right)=\pi e\left(-s+\frac12\right)=\pi e\left((1-s)-\frac12\right)$ so $\pi e\left(s-\frac12\right)+\pi e\left((1-s)-\frac12\right)=2\pi e\left(s-\frac12\right)$, which is $0\bmod{2\pi}$.

Comment: @ robjohn: I know that $g(1-s)+g(s)=0 \pmod{2\pi}$ and $f(1-s)f(s)=1$ holds in the set S={(1/2)+i0}∪{((1/2),∞)×ℝ}∪{{(1/2)}×(0,∞)}. But not in the whole set $S$. My question is: Is the forms given above for $f$ and $g$ can extended to the whole complex plane or not. I notice that ϕ(s) is analytic in $ℂ$.

Comment: @RH1: for $e$ to be analytic, it needs to be constant. As long as $h:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $k:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ are odd real-analytic functions, there should be at least a small region around $\mathbb{R}$ into which $f$ and $g$ can be continued. In those regions, $f(z)f(1-z)=1$ and $g(z)+g(1-z)\equiv0\pmod{2\pi}$.

Comment: @ robjohn: But $s$ is a complex number in the question. the departing set of $h$, $e$ and $k$ is the complex plane.

Comment: @RH1: yes. Since $f(z)f(1-z)=1$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(z)f(1-z)$ is harmonic, $f(z)f(1-z)=1$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ robjohn: The equation $f(z)f(1-z)=1$ does not holds for all real $z$.

Comment: @RH1: I thought that that was given in the question. What is the purpose of the functional equations in the question, then?

Comment: @ robjohn: The objective is to determine $f$ and $g$ and their domain of definition. Or the domain where the two equations holds in the same time.

Comment: @RH1: Unless more information is given on $\phi$ or $f$ and $g$, I don't see a way to get much more information.

Comment: @ robjohn: Ok, we have $ϕ(s)=r(s)Γ(1-s)$ where $r$ is an elementary function with a clear expression in $s$. The function $f$ and $g$ can be calculated from the expression of $ϕ(s)$. But they still depend on $Γ(1-s)$

Comment: Since $\phi(s)=f(s)e^{ig(s)}$, the functional equations say that $\phi(s)\phi(1-s)=1$. Are $f$ and $g$ real-valued functions?

Comment: @ robjohn: Yes, for all complex $s$.

Comment: @RH1: so we know that $\phi(s)\phi(1-s)=1$ and $f(s)=|\phi(s)|$ and $g(s)=\mathrm{arg}(\phi(s))$. $g$ may have to have branch cuts connecting points where $\phi(s)=0$, but otherwise, it should be possible to continue $f$ and $g$ wherever $\phi$ is defined.

Comment: @ robjohn: I know that this is a complicated question. However, $ϕ(s)≠0$ for all complex number $s$ in the chosen domain .

Comment: @RH1: I had assumed $\phi$ was entire. $\phi(s)=\infty$ is just as problematic as $\phi(s)=0$. If $\phi(s)\ne0$ and $\phi$ is entire, then $f$ and $g$ can be well-defined without branch cuts.

Comment: @ robjohn: So, the forms given above for $f$  and $g$  can extended to the whole complex plane without any problem.

Comment: @RH1: if $\phi$ is entire and never vanishes, then yes. Poles and zeros would require branch cuts, but without poles or zeros, there should be no problem.